# Why does "git pull" sometimes ask me for a merge request comment?

Tags: git

I've seen that sometimes, I haven't queued up anything for committing. I do a

```
git status
```

and that fetches me "nothing committed". After that I do a

```
git pull
```

which gets all the updates from the remote repository. One would expect the command to end there, right? But instead, it gives me a vim editor with the message "add your comment for the merge".

What is going on here? What is git trying to merge exactly when I do a pull? It seems to happen randomly.

Answer (score 2):

The thing to be aware of is that `git pull` not only gets the updates from the remote repository, but also integrates (merges) them with your local branch.

If you haven't touched your local branch, then `git pull` will simply update your branch to the remote's version (also called a fast-forward). However, if you have made any commits on your local version, then your branch and the remote has diverged, and in order to merge the remote back in, git needs to create a merge commit. That's why you're only sometimes asked for a merge commit message.

In the below example (from `git help pull`), you cloned the remote repository at commit E. Then you made commits F, and G. In the meantime, A, B and C were committed on the remote. Then, when you tell git to pull those updates, it creates merge commit H.

```
      A---B---C origin/master
     /         \
D---E---F---G---H master
```

If you only want to see the updates from the remote, but not actually merge them into your local branch, use `git fetch` instead of `git pull`. (`git pull` is basically `git fetch` + `git merge`.) Then you can review the history on the remote with `git log origin/master`.

Comment: You can often `pull --rebase` if the local commits are purely local. Good explanation of why this happens though.

Comment: If you're happy with the merge, but just don't want to be prompted for the commit message, you can set the environment variable `GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT` to `no`.

Comment: From your answer it sounds like that merge which takes place is only valid for the local repository. In other words, git fetches the updates from the remote, merges them with the existing local repository. And for this merge it creates a new commit. However, I believe when we check the commit on the remote repository then whatever comment that you have typed during the merge also appears on the remote repository. Does this sound normal?

Comment: No, that's not normal - your new merge commit should not be visible in the remote repository unless you `git push` your changes.

Comment: @kvikshaug I might have done a git push then. Okay here's the sequence of events. Let's say the master is 3 commits ahead of my local repository. And I have 2 commits of my own in my local repository (unstaged). Now I do a pull and receive those 3 commits into my local (which creates a commit message). Next, I stage my own 2 existing commits onto the staging area and then push it (git push). So now the remote repository shows 3 commits = 2 of my own + 1 that occurred while merging. Why should that 1 commit appear in the remote at all? It isn't adding any value right? Is there a name for it?

Comment: It is called a merge commit and it adds value because it shows an accurate description of the history. For example, new functions added in the remote weren't available when you made your two commits. If there were merge conflicts, you would resolve them in the merge commit. As D. Ben Knoble pointed out, you can avoid merge commits using rebase. (Side note: A commit cannot be "staged" or "unstaged" - I recommend you [read up on git](https://git-scm.com/docs))